# Javascript Currying with .bind(), how do you set the second paramater?

Tags: javascript

I have a question about currying with `.bind()` in javascript.

I understand if you have something like:

```
    function greet(a, b) {
    .... }

var greeting = greet.bind(this, "Hello");
```

It sets up the 'a' parameter to be "Hello", but how would I go about skipping 'a' and just setting the 'b' parameter as "Hello"?

Kind of like:

```
var greeting = greet.bind(this, SKIP, "Hello");
```